# How to use multithreading to run DHT22 temperature sensor with Tkinter GUI on Python

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, tkinter

I am currently trying to implement a DHT22 temperature and humidity sensor with Tkinter GUI using python on a Raspberry Pi 4. I've tried simply adding the code for the DHT22 to the GUI code, however this will cause the GUI to lag whenever the sensor refreshes every 2 seconds. Hence, I've resorted to multithreading to allow both the sensor and GUI to run simultaneously.
Here is what I have come up with so far:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import spidev
import time
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.font as tkFont
from PIL import ImageTk, Image    
import smbus
import serial
import os
import sys
import argparse
import Adafruit_DHT
import threading
SENSOR = Adafruit_DHT.DHT22

# GPIO4 on the Raspberry Pi
SENSOR_PIN = 4

address = 0b01
ssPin = 8
spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0,0)
spi.max_speed_hz = 976000
spi.mode = 0b11 
#spi.bit_order = msbfirst
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(ssPin,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(4,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(22,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(26,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(ssPin,GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(4,GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(22,GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(26,GPIO.HIGH)
print(Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(SENSOR, SENSOR_PIN))
global powerBool
global directionBool
def GUI():
    class App:
        def __init__(self, master):
            def SendScaleReading(self):
                S = scale.get() #retrieve value from slider
                if S>0:
                    S+=155
                print(S)
                spi.xfer([address ,S]) #write data to slave address
            frame = Frame(master)
            frame.pack()
            scale = tkinter.Scale(root,from_=0,to=100, width=69, length=700,bg='black',fg='#FFFFFF', highlightthickness = 0, bd = 0, command=SendScaleReading) #set parameters of slider
            scale.place(relx=0.75, rely=0.05)
            #scale.place(relx = 0, rely = 0) # set position of slider
            fontstyle = tkFont.Font(family='Arial', size=50) #initialise font
            scale['font'] = fontstyle
    def PowerFn():
        global powerBool
        #     print(ledBool)
        #powerBool = True  # boolean for led button
        if powerBool:
            #print('went to on button')
            powerBtn.config(image=On_BtnImg)
            powerBtn.image = On_BtnImg
            print("on button configured")
            powerLabel.config(text="POWER: ON", fg='#00FF00')
            GPIO.output(26,GPIO.LOW)
        else:
            #print('went to off button')
            powerBtn.config(image=Off_BtnImg)
            powerBtn.image = Off_BtnImg
            print("off button configured")
            powerLabel.config(text="POWER: OFF", fg='#FF0000')
            GPIO.output(26,GPIO.HIGH)
        powerBool = not powerBool

    def DirectionFn():
        global directionBool
        #     print(cbBool)
        if directionBool:
            #print('went to CbOn button')
            directionBtn.config(image = On_BtnImg)
            directionBtn.image = On_BtnImg
            print("CbOn button configured")
            directionLabel.config(text="FORWARD", fg='#00FF00')
            GPIO.output(22,GPIO.HIGH)
        else:
            #print('went to CbOff button')
            directionBtn.config(image = Off_BtnImg)
            directionBtn.image = Off_BtnImg
            print("CbOff button configured")
            directionLabel.config(text="REVERSE", fg='#FF0000')
            GPIO.output(22,GPIO.LOW)
        directionBool = not directionBool
    root = Tk() 
    app = App(root)
    root.config(bg='black')
    #root.attributes('-zoomed', True)
    #root.state('fullscreen')
    rootWidth = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    rootHeight = root.winfo_screenheight()
    root.attributes('-zoomed', True)
    # Create mini window
    #canvas = Canvas(root, bg='black', highlightbackground='white')
    #canvas.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.03, relheight=0.51, relwidth=0.505)
    temperature = StringVar()
    temperature.set("----"+" *C")
    humidity = StringVar()
    humidity.set("----"+" %")
    On_img = Image.open("/home/pi/Downloads/on.png")
    Off_img = Image.open("/home/pi/Downloads/off.png")
    # Resize the image using resize() method according to the screen height and width
    btnWidth = int(rootWidth / 6.4)
    print(btnWidth)
    infobtnWidth = int(rootHeight / 10)
    print(infobtnWidth)
    
    On_resize_img = On_img.resize((btnWidth, btnWidth))
    Off_resize_img = Off_img.resize((btnWidth, btnWidth))
    On_BtnImg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(On_resize_img)
    Off_BtnImg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Off_resize_img)
    
    normalWidth = 1920  # Width of monitor screen used to write this code
    normalHeight = 1080  # Height of monitor screen used to write this code
    
    percentWidth = rootWidth / (normalWidth / 100)
    percentHeight = rootHeight / (normalHeight / 100)
    
    scale = ((percentWidth + percentHeight) / 2) / 100
    
    fontsize = int(14 * scale)
    fontsize = 50
    fontstyle = tkFont.Font(family='Arial', size=fontsize)
    
    titleFontsize = int(50 * scale)
    if titleFontsize < 8:
        titleFontsize = 8
    TitleFontstyle = tkFont.Font(family="Gothic", size=titleFontsize)
    ## Labels ##
    titleLabel = Label(root, text="MAX5487 DigiPot", font=TitleFontstyle, fg="red", bg="black")
    titleLabel.place(relx=0.35, rely=0.05)
    
    powerLabel = Label(root, text="POWER: OFF", font=fontstyle, fg='red', bg='black')
    powerLabel.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.65, anchor=N)
    directionLabel = Label(root, text="FORWARD", font=fontstyle, fg='#00FF00', bg='black')
    directionLabel.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.65 , anchor=N)
    
    powerBool = True  # boolean for led button
    powerBtn = Button(root, image=Off_BtnImg, bg='black', bd=0, activebackground='black', highlightthickness = 0, command=PowerFn)
    powerBtn.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.35, anchor=N)
    
    directionBool = False
    directionBtn = Button(root, image=On_BtnImg, bg='black', bd=0, activebackground='black', highlightthickness = 0, command=DirectionFn)
    directionBtn.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.35, anchor=N)
    
    # Button for closing
    exit_button = Button(root, text="Exit", font=fontstyle, fg='white', bg='red', highlightthickness = 0, command=root.destroy)
    exit_button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.9, anchor=N)
    
    root.mainloop()

def tempsensor():
    root = Tk()
    app = App(root)
    root.config(bg='black')
    temperature = StringVar()
    temperature.set("----"+" *C")
    humidity = StringVar()
    humidity.set("----"+" %")
    normalWidth = 1920  # Width of monitor screen used to write this code
    normalHeight = 1080  # Height of monitor screen used to write this code
    rootWidth = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    rootHeight = root.winfo_screenheight()
    percentWidth = rootWidth / (normalWidth / 100)
    percentHeight = rootHeight / (normalHeight / 100)
    
    scale = ((percentWidth + percentHeight) / 2) / 100
    fontsize = int(14 * scale)
    fontsize = 50
    fontstyle = tkFont.Font(family='Arial', size=fontsize)
    root.after(2000, tempsensor)
    h, t = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(SENSOR, SENSOR_PIN)
    temp = "%.1f" %t
    temperature.set(temp+" *C")
    hum = "%.1f" %h
    humidity.set(hum+" %")
    print(temperature)
    print(humidity)
    templabel = Label(root, textvariable=temperature, font=fontstyle, fg='white', bg='red', highlightthickness = 0)
    templabel.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.8, anchor=N)
    
    humidlabel = Label(root, textvariable=humidity, font=fontstyle, fg='white', bg='red', highlightthickness = 0)
    humidlabel.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.8, anchor=N)
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
  
    # print ID of current process
    print("ID of process running main program: {}".format(os.getpid()))
  
    # print name of main thread
    print("Main thread name: {}".format(threading.current_thread().name))
  
    # creating threads
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=GUI, name='t1')
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=tempsensor, name='t2')  
  
    # starting threads
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
  
    # wait until all threads finish
    t1.join()
    t2.join()
```

However, when I tried to run the code, it would just tell me that powerBool and directionBool are not defined. The temperature and humidity values also wouldn't show up on screen and when I tried to print the variables it would just give me 'PyO3' and other similar values. Why are these things happening and how can I fix them? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The two lines `global ...` before `def GUI()` do not create the two variables.  User `powerBool = False` and `directionalBool = False` to create them instead.  Also do create only one instance of `Tk()`.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).